# Why is a stackoverflow.com/a/{answer-id} generated by Google not working when passed to the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, api

I am writing a crawler that takes a URL from a Google search, for example https://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.stackoverflow.com+for+loop+python and use it to fetch data from Stack Overflow using the Stack Exchange API.

The URLs generated by Google are given below:

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/47720685
http://www.stackoverflow.com/Questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so
https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/48305616
http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/44063325
http://www.stackoverflow.com/Questions/4039879/best-way-to-find-the-months-between-two-dates
...etc
```

I tried passing the id from the URL's answer id https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/47720685 to the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/47720685?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow).

It is not returning any values. But when I directly visit the URL https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/47720685 it is pointing to the correct question.

How is this happening? Is there any way to get the result via the Stack Exchange API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer 47720685 has been deleted, and the API doesn't provide information about deleted posts. The website still redirects you to the question, but doesn't show the answer (unless you are its author or have more than 10k reputation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So as of now there's no way to get the question id of the deleted answer other than crawling the site right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.